# jquery $.post doesn't work with setTimeout()

Tags: jquery

kindly have a look at this code:

```
$('a.load').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".content_container").append('<div class="preloading"><img src="http://localhost:8888/smart/assets/images/loading.gif" alt="loading" /></div>').show();   
            var url = 'http://localhost:8888/smart/payments.html';
            $.post(url,function(data){
                $('.content_container').append(data).show();
                $('.preloading').remove();
            });             
        },1000);    
});
```

the problem that it doesn't return the required url, just the loading image only, it's just html pages

Comment: What does Firebug tell you is coming back from the server?

Comment: mmm good idea, i will check firebug debugger and tell you :)

Comment: @PaulTomblin could you tell me how to check what it comes back from the server

Comment: In the console, you should see the POST. Open it up by clicking on the plus sign. You should see tabs for the request and the response. If you don't see the POST, it means the call never got made, possibly because you didn't install the click handler correctly.

Comment: @PaulTomblin i didn't see the post, so the click handler was incorrect, could you have another further look again

Comment: _"jquery_ `$.post` _doesn't work with_ `setTimeout()`" - Are you saying the same `$.post()` code works within that click handler if you remove the `setTimeout()` part?

Comment: Try the same code without the `setTimeout()` function and see what happens. On the callback function try: `console.log(data)` and see what happens start eliminating problems one by one. Also, you are `$.posting` to an html page without passing on the object as a second parameter, what kind of response are you getting? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @PaulTomblin i check the console the post doesn't return values in the html or response, even when i remove the setTimeout()

Comment: You accepted an answer already, why are you still asking questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are referencing localhost:8888, are you running the above code on that same domain? If you are not then I suspect that you are falling prey to the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: yes it was at the same domain, when i call the page from the browser it works fine for me

Comment: If its the same domain, why did you accept this as an answer?  Did it solve your problem or not?

Comment: 1) You should post an answer as something that should be a comment. 2) The original posters should not have accepted an answer that is clearly not an answer.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a comment option on the above question. I can see a comment button on my own answer, however.